# Warning Notice $wpdb->prepare incorrect number of arguments passed

Tags: notices, wpdb

I am receiving this notice when trying to use the $wpdb->prepare function:

> Notice: wpdb::prepare was called **incorrectly**. The
>   query does not contain the correct number of placeholders (7) for the
>   number of arguments passed (4). Please see Debugging in
>   WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version
>   4.8.3.) in C:\wamp\www\wpml\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4139

I looked at other posts on this topic and I don't see any of the same problems from those threads in my code. When developing this notice greatly slows down my application so I want to find a solution.

```
function get_meta_range($meta_key) {
    global $wpdb;

    // $meta_key = '_price'
    $include = '7275,7266,7256,7237,7196,7192,7164';

    $min = floor( $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare('
            SELECT min(meta_value + 0)
            FROM %1$s
            LEFT JOIN %2$s ON %1$s.ID = %2$s.post_id
            WHERE ( meta_key =\'%3$s\' OR meta_key =\'%4$s\' )
            AND meta_value != ""
            AND (
                %1$s.ID IN (' . $include . ')
            )'
        , $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta, $meta_key, '_min_variation' . $meta_key )
    ) );

    // $min = 15
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Numbered placeholders don't work as you'd expect, and are going to be removed altogether at some point in the future, so should be considered invalid syntax.

So with this in mind, the error describes the problem- your query has 7 placeholders, but you only pass 4 values. For the repeated values, you just need to repeat them where you pass the substitutions.

Comment: Milo - I understand your answer but not sure on the syntax. Could you provide some example code to clarify?

Comment: I have run into this issue a few times now, and totally believe your response, however I can't find any documentation to qualify the statement, "Numbered placeholders don't work as you'd expect, and are going to be removed altogether at some point in the future..." Is there a link that can be referenced?

Answer (score 1):

The `wpdb::prepare` says that you should not quote placeholders, yet in your code there is:

```
WHERE ( meta_key =\'%3$s\' OR meta_key =\'%4$s\' )
```

Also keep in mind that the meta table is designed to be fast when you already know the post ID, and WP already fetches all of the meta when you grab a post.

So it would actually be much faster to use `get_post_meta` and calculate it in PHP, as the data has already been requested. Doing this query is both unnecessary, and potentially expensive

Comment: Tom - Can you provide some code to make what your saying more clear, not sure I understand. My code finds all available filtered posts within a range of min/max values based off the meta key, price in this case. The $include var holds the post ids I want to limit my query too.

Comment: @George you put quotes around your placeholders, e.g. `\'%3$s\'` versus `%3$s`. The docs explicitly say not to do this

Comment: The first part about the quotes makes sense I was referring to the second part of your answer that mentioned the speed increase using a different technique then what I am using

Comment: You'd fetch all the post meta for the posts you want to test, then manually check the lowest and highest values. Think of it the same way as if someone gave you 12 books full of numbers and asked you to find the lowest and the highest, you'd open each book starting from the first page and going to the last page reading each number, and if the number is the highest of the lowest, you'd write it down as the new lowest, or the new highest. It's the same, but in PHP

Comment: Are you saying calling get_post_meta for each post is faster than my query, don't think I understand your approach. A bit of code would really help make this more clear.

Comment: I'm saying when WP gets a post from the DB it shows some initiative and fetches all the post meta for that post in advance so it doesn't have to make lots of small DB queries. As for code I'm a firm believer that if you don't understand it in plain english then copypasta will do no good. *For each post, grab the meta, and check if it's lower than the lowest, or higher than the highest, and keep track of the highest you've seen and the lowest you've seen.*, a for loop with 2 if statements inside